fineract: response status is 404 /fineract-provider/fineract.json
I have setup fineract using following command in my Windows using WSL, and every thing was successful:
git clone https://github.com/apache/fineract.git ; cd fineract for windows, use git clone https://github.com/apache/fineract.git --config core.autocrlf=input ; cd fineract ./gradlew :fineract-provider:jibDockerBuild -x test install the Loki log driver with docker plugin install grafana/loki-docker-driver:latest --alias loki --grant-all-permissions docker compose -f docker-compose-development.yml up -d fineract (back-end) is running at https://localhost:8443/fineract-provider/ wait for https://localhost:8443/fineract-provider/actuator/health to return {"status":"UP"} you must go to https://localhost:8443 and remember to accept the self-signed SSL certificate of the API once in your browser, otherwise you get a message that is rather misleading from the UI. community-app (UI) is running at http://localhost:9090/?baseApiUrl=https://localhost:8443/fineract-provider&tenantIdentifier=default
But as i try to run this link locally,
https://localhost:8443/fineract-provider/swagger-ui/index.html
I got this error
response status is 404 /fineract-provider/fineract.json
I m not sure, what i m missing.
I tried to change java version from 17 to 18, and still no luck. Also i try deleting completely local setup and did every thing again, and not luck
